# Relation between partial derivative and ordinary derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand how the two relate from this definition

[image]

From my understanding, this definition of $D_{j} f(\vec a)$ is expanded as

$$D_{j} f(\vec a) = lim \frac{(f(a_{1}+te_{j_{1}} , .... , a_{m} + te_{j_{m}}) - f(a_{1} , ... a_{m}))}{t}$$

No special cases, I'm treating $\vec e_{j}$ as if it has non zero components,

Now with the definition of $ \phi(t) = f(a_{1} , ... , a_{j-1} , t , a_{j+1} , ... , a_{m})$

The ordinary derivative of $\phi(t)$ is:

$$\phi'(t) = lim \frac{\phi(t+h) - \phi(t)}{h}$$

Using the definition of $\phi(t)$ , it is expanded as:

$$\phi'(t) = lim \frac{ f(a_{1} , ... , a_{j-1} , t+h , a_{j+1} , ... , a_{m}) - f(a_{1} , ... , a_{j-1} , t , a_{j+1} , ... , a_{m})}{h}$$

and at $t=a_{j}$ it becomes:

$$\phi'(t) = lim \frac{ f(a_{1} , ... , a_{j-1} , a_{j}+h , a_{j+1} , ... , a_{m}) - f(a_{1} , ... , a_{j-1} , a_{j} , a_{j+1} , ... , a_{m})}{h}$$

So how are $\phi'(a_{j})$ and $D_{j}f(\vec a)$ the same? I can't see the connection.

Also I believe the parameter $t$ in $\phi$ is not the same as the $t$ in the limit of $D_{j}f(\vec a)$

Comment: The partial derivative $(D_jf)(a)$ is by definition obtained when you put $e_j = (0, \dots 1, \dots 0)$, with $1$ in the $j^{th}$ place. Once you make this simplification, the two limits will be identical.

Comment: But this is a very special case, using the standard basis vectors, no?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what a partial derivative is. It is a directional derivative along the direction of a basis vector. In $\Bbb{R}^n$, we have a "standard" choice of basis vectors, so these are the basis vectors we choose.

Comment: what if the directional derivative was along a basis vector that is not zero in all components except one?

Comment: In the definition you quoted, $e_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector.

Comment: as I mentioned in the previous comment, in $\Bbb{R}^n$, the term "partial derivative" by definition means taking the directional derivative along one of the vectors $e_j = (0, \dots, 1 , \dots 0)$. That's just definition. Of course, nothing is stopping you from considering directional derivatives along different vectors. It's just that no one calls them partial derivatives anymore. You can consider $(D_vf)(a):=\dfrac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0}f(a+tv)$; this we just call the directional derivative along $v$.

Comment: To connect a directional derivative to single variable calculus, one thing you could say is that if you define $\phi(t) = f(a + t v)$, then $\phi'(0) = D_v f(a)$, the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ in the direction $v$.

Comment: Now I think this definition makes more sense to me, thank you both